# Looking for a short story where a guy travels through time in the London underground

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read this story around 10-12 years ago but was probably written in the 1990s or earlier.

Here's what I recall: There's a guy (I want to say his name's John, but not too sure about that) who goes into the London underground and ends up visiting a platform he's never seen before. It turns out that he has somehow travelled to the past (19th century, I believe). He sees that all the people there are wearing Victorian clothes.
One phrase from the story that's stuck with me all these years is *brass spittoon* since that's the first time (and probably the last time) I've seen that phrase being used.

Comment: @Edlothiad my question is indeed a duplicate of the question Bells mentioned. Please close it.

Comment: As I suggested, one of you should post an answer, Or I can post a quick one (I'd prefer if @Bells did it) you can accept it (So it's catalogued) and then we can close it more comfortably.

Comment: Do we really need an answer here is the OP knows for sure it's the other one?

Comment: Well, @Bells did confirm the answer, but not the correct way. He did it in the comment under the answer, more than a year ago. Can a mod accept that answer for him?

Comment: I can see a tick next to the answer. Doesn't that mean it's accepted?

Comment: @TakeruDavis: No. They cannot.

Comment: @sudhanva: Yes. The other answer is accepted, so we can close this one as a Dupe.

Comment: Wait, was it (the answer to the other question) already accepted. I didn't notice the check mark before...

Comment: @TakeruDavis Yes, Bells accepted the answer in 2016, half an hour after it was posted.